# Change space between lines of gwt grid panel

Tags: gwt, grid, space

I have a 10x5 sized grid panel with one textbox in every cell. My problem is, that the grid is too big, especially too high.

What I tried so far:

1) I changed the textbox size to (50,8) with the result that the textboxes are now less high, but the space between the cell lines is now larger, so the overall size of the grid hasn't changed.

2) Set the grid height to 50px but with no effect: `myGrid.setCellPadding(0)`

3) Set `myGrid.setCellSpacing(0)`, with no effect

4) Set `myGrid.setHeight("10px")` with no effect

The code:

```
TextBox[] boxArray= new TextBox[15];

Grid boxGrid = new Grid(10,3);

boxGrid.setCellPadding(0);
boxGrid.setCellSpacing(0);
boxGrid.setHeight("10px");

int boxIndex = 0;
for ( int i=0; i<5; i++ )
{
  for (int j=0; j<3; j++ )
  {
    boxArray[boxIndex] = new TextBox();
    boxArray[boxIndex].setReadOnly(true);
    boxArray[boxIndex].setPixelSize(50, 6);
    boxArray[boxIndex].getElement().setId("answerBox" + boxIndex);
    boxArray[boxIndex].setVisible(true);
    boxArray[boxIndex].setText("0");
    boxGrid.setWidget(i,j,boxArray[boxIndex]);            
    boxIndex++;
  }
}
RootPanel.add( boxGrid );
```

Comment: Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: It would be great if you can share the code to replicate the issue.

Comment: I added the code above